# Existe alguma diferença ou vantagem de usar eventos drag and drop e eventos de mouse?

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background: #dddddd;
        }

        ::selection {
            background: transparent;
        }

        #container {
            width: 300px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid #919191;
            padding: 30px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        #drag, #drop {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 100px;
            font-family: arial;
            color: #505050;
        }

        #drag {
            background: #ffffff;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #drop {
            border: 1px solid #919191;
            position: absolute;
            right: 30px;
            top: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="drag" draggable="true">Drag</div>
        <div id="drop">Drop</div>
    </div>

    <script>
        let drag = document.querySelector("#drag");
        let drop = document.querySelector("#drop");

        drag.ondragstart = (event) => {
            event.dataTransfer.setData("div", event.target.id);
        }

        drop.ondragover = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        drop.ondrop = (event) => {
            let draggableDice = event.dataTransfer.getData("div");

            event.preventDefault();
            drop.innerHTML = "";
            drop.appendChild(document.querySelector(`#${draggableDice}`));
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

No exemplo acima eu utilizo a propriedade `dataTransfer` e seus métodos junto com os eventos de *drag and drop* para realizar uma operação de *drag and drop*, mas o mesmo resultado eu tenho se usar apenas eventos do mouse:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background: #dddddd;
        }

        ::selection {
            background: transparent;
        }

        #container {
            width: 300px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid #919191;
            padding: 30px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        #drag, #drop {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 100px;
            font-family: arial;
            color: #505050;
        }

        #drag {
            background: #ffffff;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #drop {
            border: 1px solid #919191;
            position: absolute;
            right: 30px;
            top: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="drag" draggable="true">Drag</div>
        <div id="drop">Drop</div>
    </div>

    <script>
        let drag = document.querySelector("#drag");
        let drop = document.querySelector("#drop");

        drag.onmousedown = () => {
            drop.onmouseenter = () => {
                drop.innerHTML = "";
                drop.appendChild(drag);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Existe alguma diferença ou vantagem entre usar um e o outro?

Comment: Fundamental [edit] o post e reduzir o problema a um [mcve] com uma dúvida específica. O  [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70) pode ajudar a entender melhor nosso modelo.

Comment: Eu apenas coloquei essas duas etapas do código para vocês ver o quão da para reduzir o código sem usar os métodos do `dataTransfer` e os eventos drag and drop.

Comment: Sim eu já li as regras do site, mas na minha pergunta eu reduzi o código e deixei mais compreensivo o possível. As perguntas são relacionadas as dúvida da própria pergunta ambas não são diferentes. Não vejo o motivo de você ter fechado a minha pergunta.

Comment: Algumas observações: a pergunta ja estava reaberta fazia praticamente 10 minutos ANTES desse comentário. Esse tipo de "campanha" pra reabrir não é a maneira de resolver as coisas, a comunidade reabre pelo conteúdo, seja pela fila de análise e não simplesmente por que está sendo pedido. No caso específico eu reabri por estar com os dois exemplos e você ter deixado a pergunta mais objetiva, e principalmente por não ser "pergunta de helpdesk". Sempre que quiser um post aberto, basta seguir o guia e fazer postagens relevantes para a comunidade como um todo, que o resto normalmente acontece.

Comment: Obrigado! @Bacco :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe muita diferença, até porque no seu segundo exemplo (usando eventos do mouse) isso não funciona. Você está criando um *falso efeito* de arrastar e soltar.

Veja: quando você clica na div "drag" você dispara o evento `onmousedown` e dentro dele cria outro escutador de evento `onmouseenter`. Mesmo sem arrastar essa div para a div "drop", o escutador foi criado e assim que o mouse, em qualquer momento, passar sobre a div "drop", será disparado o evento `onmouseenter` fazendo com que a div "drag" seja transferida para dentro dela, mesmo sem ela ter sido arrastada pra lá

Já no primeiro exemplo, o recurso de arrastar e soltar funciona adequadamente, ou seja, a div "drag" só será inserida na div "drop" se ela for de fato arrastada pra lá.

Deve usar os eventos do *drag & drop* e não do mouse para arrastar elementos.

Comment: Verdade! boa observação, vlw!